# How do I fix the "we can't reach this page" error or "err_connection_timed_out" on my browsers?

Tags: google-chrome, timeout, microsoft-edge

I am currently experiencing an error everytime I use my Microsoft Edge. Whenever I try to go to a site, I always end up with this error. The weird thing is, this issue only happens on certain websites (such as Facebook and Yahoo currently) and sometimes with Google. It likes to disconnect me often and I really don't want to have to deal with this issue anymore.

My internet works fine as my laptop (which I'm currently on) and phone can connect to it without issue. I don't know why it doesn't work on my desktop especially since its internet is Ethernet.

I tested this on other browsers to see if it was only on Edge but it turns out that chrome and firefox experience the same issue with different sites as well. For all three, I haven't been able to go on Facebook and Yahoo, and sometimes Google.

I know the problem is from my end because clearly, the sites are up. Is there any way to solve this or has anyone else found a solution to this?

I'm running Windows 10.

I've tried the following:

- ipconfig / flush
- ipconfig / reset
- ipconfig / release
- ipconfig / renew
- clearing caches and browsing history
- a full scan for malware using malwarebytes and windows defender, already removed/quarantined all threats, did this multiple times to ensure there were none left
- reinstallation of chrome and firefox and a reset of edge
- ipv4 - changing preferred and alternate dns address to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.8.4 respectively
- checked to see if a proxy was up, no proxy

If I were to do a factory reset, would this solve the issue?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To narrow it down a bit, can you confirm that you only get this when navigating to the sites listed and they're using SSL / HTTPS? Some will auto re-direct to HTTPS if you go to their non-SSL equivalent, but it's worth trying this on sites like Google which do support both.

If this does help narrow down the behaviour, then I've seen this behaviour once before, but this was behind a corporate proxy which didn't support SSL SPDY.

You can try disabling SPDY support, but there is likely to be an underlying issue (perhaps anti-virus acting as a proxy?).

To test disabling SPDY:

> **Internet Explorer 11**
>
> In the browser, select Tools > Internet Options > Advanced > HTTP
>   Settings and clear the Use SPDY/3 option.
>
> **Firefox**
>
> In the browser, enter **about:config** in the address bar and press
>   Enter. Confirm the security warning. Type
>   **network.http.spdy.enabled** in the Search field. For all the entries, set the Value to false.
>
> **Chrome**
>
> Use a switch to disable SPDY for Chrome. Edit the shortcut for Chrome
>   and add the following switch at the end of the Target path:
>
> **--use-spdy=off**
>
> For example, if Chrome's default shortcut link is pointing to
>   "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe", change it to
>   "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" –use-spdy=off.

Source:-
http://bluecoat.force.com/knowledgebase/articles/Solution/HowtodisableSPDYprotocolsupportinbrowsers

Comment: any idea about linux chromium...?

Answer (score 1):

I had a caller who was getting the "can't load page" error in Chrome only when logging into the AMEX site.  Every other browser worked.  The fix was to disable some weird experimental Chrome setting that is on by default.  `Go to chrome://flags,  search for "experimental quic protocol" and "Disable" it.`

[Source](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/sv0YttC20cU)

Answer (score 1):

The problem I was facing was apparently with my ISP. When I changed my Wi-Fi network and switched over to cellular, the website started working.

Answer (score 0):

Click on start/control pane/IE options/Privacy Tab/Sites
Look at list of sites to see if any Google sites are blocked.

Comment: this did not work as I could not find the IE options and privacy tab